# Decoupling single spider into different spiders in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to decouple parsing into a different spiders.

Currently I have:

```
class CategoriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'categories'
    allowed_domains = ['example.org']
    start_urls = ['https://example.org/categories']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='something']/@href"):
          yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link.root), callback=self.parse_actual_item_i_want)

    def parse_actual_item_i_want(self, response):
          yield self.find_the_item(response)
```

And now split it into:

```
class OneThingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'one_thing'
    allowed_domains = ['example.org']
    start_urls = ['https://example.org/']

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        if url == None or url == "":
            raise ValueError("Invalid url given")

        # Exact URL and it's format is not known
        self.start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
          yield self.find_the_item(response)
```

So that if only one thing is updated I can only use `OneThingSpider`

So where and how I call the `OneThingSpider` inside `CategoriesSpider` or pipeline?

### I've tried these:

#### Inside the `CategoriesSpider` attempt #1:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='something']/@href"):
          yield self.crawler.crawl("one_thing", response.urljoin(link.root))
```

#### In the pipeline attempt #1:

In `CategoriesSpider`:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//div[@class='something']/@href"):
          yield CategoryUrl({"url": response.urljoin(link.root)})
```

In pipeline:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, CategoryUrl):
            spider.crawler.crawl("one_thing", item["url"])
            return

        # this part works
        if isinstance(item, ItemIWant): 
            with open(...)
```

#### In the pipeline attempt #2:

Same change in the `CategoriesSpider` as in attempt #1. Here we simply are trying to push the URLs to the `OneThingSpider` after `CategoriesSpider` has closed.

In pipeline:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    urls = []
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, CategoryUrl):
            self.urls.append(item["url"])
            spider.crawler.crawl("one_thing", item["url"])
            return

        # this part works
        if isinstance(item, ItemIWant): 
            with open(...)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        if spider.name == "categories":
            for url in self.urls:
                spider.crawler.crawl("one_thing", url)
```

The error I get is that the **crawler is already crawling**. So what is the correct way for decoupling spider into smaller spiders?

Goal is that I can run:

```
scrapy crawl categories
```

and also

```
scrapy crawl one_thing -a url="https://example.org/something/xyz.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd use class inheritence for reusing spider code in multiple spiders:

```
class BaseSpider(Spider):
    start_urls = NotImplemented
    start_body = ""

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, method='POST', body=self.start_body)

    def parse(self, response):
        raise NotImplementedError


# then children spiders
class CakeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'cakes'
    start_urls = ['http://example1.com']
    start_body = '{"category": "cakes"}'

    def parse(self, response):
        # custom parser for first spider here

class VegetableSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'vegetables'
    start_urls = ['http://example2.com']
    start_body = '{"category": "vegetables"}'

    def parse(self, response):
        # custom parser for second spider here
```

As a result you'd run `scrapy crawl cakes` to start crawling cake category and `scrapy crawl vegetables` to crawl vegetable category.

Comment: How can I call `response.follow` with the base class? I tried: `yield response.follow(link, BaseSpider.parseDetailPage)`. But the response parameter is not filled-in anymore.

Comment: For some reason `yield response.follow(link, super().parseDetailPage)` does work..